# How to return condition codes in Rblpapi

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am trying to return condition codes in the getTicks function for Rblpapi.  The following code works fine:

require(Rblpapi)

blpConnect()

symbol <-  "SBH6 Comdty"

times <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-07 09:30:00", "2016-01-08 10:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

ticks <- getTicks(symbol, eventType = "TRADE", startTime = times[1], endTime = times[2],verbose = FALSE)

This does not:

require(Rblpapi)

blpConnect()

symbol <-  "SBH6 Comdty"

times <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-07 09:30:00", "2016-01-08 10:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

ticks <- getTicks(symbol, eventType = "TRADE", startTime = times[1], endTime = times[2],verbose = FALSE, **setCondCodes = TRUE**)

Error in getTicks(symbol, eventType = "TRADE", startTime = times[1], endTime = times[2],  : 
  unused argument (setCondCodes = TRUE)

I have the latest package installed, 0.3.2.  R version is 3.2.3.  Is anyone able to get condition codes returned from Bloomberg via Rblpapi?   I have also tried Rbbg but I don't think it is supported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

res4 <- getTicks("ADANI IS Equity", "TRADE", Sys.time()-60*60*24*31, Sys.time()-60*60*24*28)

or for multiple ticks

res5 <- getMultipleTicks("ADANI IS Equity", c("TRADE", "BID", "ASK"), Sys.time()-60*60*24*31, Sys.time()-60*60*24*25)